# Login loop with lightdm, startx works, .xsession-errors.old contains systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg, lightdm

I got a login loop in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, startx works,
installed ubuntu-desktop and made it the default and the login loop persisted, reinstalled lightdm stayed the same,

after booting with startx, .xsession-errors.old shows the following at the end which I think might be the cause of the loop

> systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized
> option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl:
> unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'
> systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized
> option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl:
> unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'
> systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized
> option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl:
> unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'
> systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized
> option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value' systemctl:
> unrecognized option '--value' systemctl: unrecognized option '--value'
> systemctl: unrecognized option '--wait'

But I don't have any script in .profile, and have no idea where systemctl is being used with --value parameter at startup.

Comment: Please clarify your release, 18 implies a *snap* only product such as Ubuntu Core 18, but you've tagged a *deb* based 18.04 system; they are different products.  (Ubuntu has had *year* based *snap* only products since 2016).

Comment: @guiverc updated with what I found in lsb_release -a